# Motor rotates well in one direction but runs slower in other with L298N and L293D

Tags: motor, arduino-uno, l298, l293d

I connected two motors with an L293N driver. When I control it with my joystick, one motor works fine (Out 1 and 2 of driver). It rotates in one direction and the other very smoothly.

The problem occurs with the second motor (Out 3 and 4 of driver). It rotates smoothly in one direction (clockwise) but when rotated in the other (anti-clockwise), the 4000 RPM motor rotates at around 60 RPM. My voltmeter shows a reading of 1V.

When I reverse the polarity at the driver, it rotates slowly in the clockwise direction and at proper speed in the anti-clockwise direction.

I tried it with another L298N driver and had the same problem. I tried with an L293D driver and still had the same error. The code is the same for both drivers. The motors work fine in both directions when connected directly to the 12V battery.

I do not understand the problem.

My code:

```
struct Signal{
  uint16_t y1; // Joystick-1 Y 0 to 1023
  uint16_t y2; // Joystick-2 Y 0 to 1023
};
int x1 = 0; // Joystick-1 Y 0 to 255
int x2 = 0; // Joystick-2 Y 0 to 255
Signal data;
#include<SPI.h>
#include<nRF24L01.h>
#include<RF24.h>
RF24 radio(7,8);
const byte address[6] = "HexaT";
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(1, OUTPUT); // motor b
  pinMode(2,OUTPUT); // motor b
  pinMode(6,OUTPUT); // motor b key
  
  pinMode(5,OUTPUT); // motor a key
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT); // motor a
  pinMode(10,OUTPUT); // motor a
  
  radio.begin();
  radio.openReadingPipe(0, address);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);
  radio.startListening();

}

void loop() {
  while(radio.available()){
    radio.read(&data, sizeof(Signal));
        

//motor A
    if(data.y1 > 530){
      x1 = map(data.y1,530,1023, 0, 255);
      analogWrite(5,x1); // motor a key
      digitalWrite(9,LOW); // motor a
      digitalWrite(10,HIGH); // motor a
    }else if(data.y1 < 500){
      x1 = map(data.y1,500,0, 0, 255);
      analogWrite(5,x1); // motor a key
      digitalWrite(9,HIGH); // motor a
      digitalWrite(10,LOW); // motor a
    }else{
      digitalWrite(5,LOW); // motor a key
      digitalWrite(9,LOW); // motor a
      digitalWrite(10,LOW); // motor a
    };

//Motor B    
    if(data.y2 > 530){
      x2 = map(data.y2,530,1023, 0, 255);
      analogWrite(6,x2); // motor b key
      digitalWrite(1,LOW); // motor b
      digitalWrite(2,HIGH); // motor b
    }else if(data.y2 < 500){
      x2 = map(data.y2,500,0, 0, 255);
      analogWrite(6,x2); // motor b key
      digitalWrite(1,HIGH); // motor b
      digitalWrite(2,LOW); // motor b
    }else{
      digitalWrite(6,LOW); // motor b key
      digitalWrite(1,LOW); // motor b
      digitalWrite(2,LOW); // motor b
    };

    Serial.println(x1);
    Serial.println(x2);
  }
}
```

In the serial monitor, I get proper values of 0..255 for both joysticks and send that PWM signal to the driver.

[image]

```
analogWrite(6,255); // motor a key
      digitalWrite(1,HIGH); // motor a
      digitalWrite(2,LOW); // motor a

      delay(1000);

      analogWrite(6,0); // motor a key
      digitalWrite(1,LOW); // motor a
      digitalWrite(2,LOW); // motor a

      delay(2000);
      
      analogWrite(6,255); // motor a key
      digitalWrite(1,LOW); // motor a
      digitalWrite(2,HIGH); // motor a

      delay(1000);

      analogWrite(6,0); // motor a key
      digitalWrite(1,LOW); // motor a
      digitalWrite(2,LOW); // motor a

      delay(2000);
```

Tried this piece of code on all my drivers removing the clever bit. What I found was that it rotated in only one direction. and didn't rotate the other way. But when I tried it with another channel (*Out 1 and 2*), it rotated both ways. So is there a problem with channels? How can it happen on 3 different drivers even though they are different models and were bought at different time from different retailers?!

Comment: @All - The long comment chain has exceeded what is reasonable for comments. Therefore it has been moved to chat and should be continued there (see the link below). --- As this bulk moving of comments to chat can only be done once per question, any further comments posted here might be deleted without notice. **Keep it in chat now, please!** When someone has got enough information from the chat to post an answer, then please do that as usual. Any updates to the question which are decided during the chat, should be made via an edit to the question, not as a comment. Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134819/discussion-on-question-by-hexatech-motor-rotates-well-in-one-direction-but-runs).

Answer (score 2):

https://forum.arduino.cc/t/using-digital-pin-0-and-1-just-like-any-other-digital-pin/462591

I was using GPIO 1 (TX) for it. I thought 0 and 1 act the same way as other pins, when not communicating via module or with serial monitor but I was wrong. I tried it with 3 and it works. Thank you to all who helped me!